# Change color after Success query of jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am Creating Inline editing webpage for my company 
here i write jquery code for sending data to config.php file and save data there

Here is my jquery code:

```
<script src="<?=base_url()?>application/views/blackline/clients/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('div.auto').click(function(){
                $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');

                $(this).addClass('ajax');
                $(this).html('<input id="editbox" size="'+$(this).text().length+'" type="text" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');

                $('#editbox').focus();

          }
          );



        $('div.auto').keydown(function(event){
                arr = $(this).attr('name').split(" ");
                if(event.which == 13)
                {   
                    $.ajax({    
                    type: "POST",
                    url:"/con.php",
                    data: "value="+$('.ajax input').val()+"&field="+arr[1]+"&table="+arr[0]+"&row="+arr[2],
                    success: function(data){

                         $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                         $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');

                    }});
                 }});

        $('#editbox').live('blur',function(){

         $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
         $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
        });



    });


</script>
```

Every thing is working fine the only thing which I want to improve is when user changed data the new data should be highlighted for few seconds with yellow background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/pms/config.php",
    data: "value=" + $('.ajax input').val() + "&field=" + arr[1] + "&table=" + arr[0] + "&row=" + arr[2],
    success: function (data) {

        $('.ajax').html('<span class="highlight" >' + $('.ajax input').val() + '</span>');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".higlight").removeClass("higlight");
        }, 1000);

    }
});
```

In your css , add this code

```
.highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

**Edit**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/pms/config.php",
    data: "value=" + $('.ajax input').val() + "&field=" + arr[1] + "&table=" + arr[0] + "&row=" + arr[2],
    success: function (data) {

        $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
        $(".ajax").css("background-color","yellow");
        $(".ajax").addClass("higlight");
        setTimeout(function () {
             $(".ajax").removeAttr("style");
            $(".higlight").removeClass("higlight");
        }, 1000);

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks this working but Can I remove entire span tag because of span tag it is taking different css too

Comment: I Applied Edited Code but here in this Code that yellow color not disappeared after few seconds

Comment: Not Working This edited Code it is not creating Even class so it not highlight the text

Comment: It's my mistak to not accept it because I don't know how to accept answer That time sorry

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout()` which calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds like shown below in the ajax response.

```
$('.ajax').show();
$('.ajax').html('<span style="background-color:yellow;">'+$('.ajax input').val()+'</span>');
setTimeout(function() { $('.ajax').hide(); }, 1000);
```

Comment: This will have a reverse effect. It will highlight the tag after 3 seconds. OP's need is to highlight the tag for 3 seconds

Comment: Thanks but I want Highlight for few seconds after success not permanently after 3 seconds

Comment: your New query showing text highlighted but it does not disapeared after few seconds